# How do I enable a second monitor in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop, multiple-monitors

Is it possible to enable a second monitor programatically and extend the Windows Desktop onto it in C#? It needs to do the equivalent of turning on the checkbox in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[MSDN Device Context Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533259.aspx)

What you basically need to do:

> Use the EnumDisplayDevices() API call
>   to enumerate the display devices on
>   the system and look for those that
>   don't have the
>   `DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP`
>   flag set (this will include any
>   mirroring devices so not all will be
>   physical displays.) Once you've found
>   the display device you'll need to get
>   a valid display mode to change it to,
>   you can find this by calling the
>   EnumDisplaySettingsEx() API call -
>   Generally you'd display all the
>   available modes and allow the user to
>   choose however in your case it sounds
>   like this may be possible to hard-code
>   and save you an additional step. For
>   the sake of future-proofing your
>   application though I'd suggest having
>   this easily changeable without having
>   to dig through the source every time,
>   a registry key would be the obvious
>   choice. Once you've got that sorted
>   out populate a DevMode display
>   structure with the information about
>   the display positioning (set the
>   PelsWidth/Height, Position,
>   DisplayFrequency and BitsPerPel
>   properties) then set these flags in
>   the fields member. Finally call
>   ChangeDisplaySettingsEx() with this
>   settings structure and be sure to send
>   the reset and update registry flags.
>   That should be all you need, hope this
>   helps,

[DISPLAY_DEVICE](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/DISPLAY_DEVICE.html) structure import using PInvoke

[EnumDisplayDevices](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumDisplayDevices.html) function import

[EnumDisplaySettingsEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumDisplaySettingsEx.html) function import

etc. the rest of them functions can be found with a simple search by name.

Comment: Hi Pop, I can use your method if the secondary monitor is already enabled, but I can't use it to turn on the secondary method, it always fails. Should this method be able to do this?

Comment: This could be a driver specific issue, the driver doesn't automatically enable a monitor when the api sets's some valid monitor settings. In my case I was working with some old Matrox card, and I didn't have this issue. It might be useful to look up some specific manufacturer docs.

Comment: Or better yet, ask the question on MSDN driver development forums :)

Answer (score 12):

If you have windows 7, then just start a process:

```
    private static Process DisplayChanger = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "DisplaySwitch.exe",
            Arguments = "/extend"
        }
    };
```

then DisplayChanger.Start();

Comment: Works to enable 1 monitor on first display adapter but not on second display adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the full answer here but I am almost sure that you will have to call out of .Net to do this.  You will have to use Pinvoke to call an unmanaged dll.  A great resource for this is pinvoke.net.

I did a quick search and found http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ChangeDisplaySettings.html which probably isn't exactly what you want but you will probably find it somewhere on pinvoke.net

Answer (score 2):

I am looking for the same solution. I have written the following code to call `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` with PInvoke:

```
DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE();
dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm);
dm.dmPelsWidth = 1680;
dm.dmPelsHeight = 1050;
dm.dmBitsPerPel = 32;
dm.dmDisplayFrequency = 60;
dm.dmFields = DevModeFields.DM_BITSPERPEL | DevModeFields.DM_PELSWIDTH | 
              DevModeFields.DM_PELSHEIGHT | DevModeFields.DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY;
int res = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(@"\\.\DISPLAY2", ref dm, IntPtr.Zero, CDS_RESET | CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, IntPtr.Zero);
Console.WriteLine("result = " + res.ToString());
```

If the monitor is already enabled, this changes the resolution successfully. But if the monitor isn't attached to the desktop already, this won't activate it. So does anyone have a code example that works?

Answer (score 1):

To enable a monitor, set its position to something other than 0,0, like as shown:

```
POINTL enabledPosition = new POINTL();
enabledPosition.x = -1280;
enabledPosition.y = 0;

dm.dmPosition = enabledPosition;
dm.dmFields = DM.Position;
res = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(d.DeviceName, ref dm, IntPtr.Zero, (uint) DeviceFlags.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY, IntPtr.Zero);
```