# set desktop to extend/clone in dual display in windows

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp

How can I programmaticly change windows display setting from Extend desktop to Clone desktop and the other way around ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue isn't going to be a simple "call this method in this .NET class" I don't believe.  However, it can be done using the `EnumDisplaySettingsEx()` API.  Here is a SO question similar to yours that has the information you need to dig into this issue:

[How do I enable a second monitor in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233411/how-do-i-enable-a-second-monitor-in-c)

Comment: Hmmm, its long ago, but I cannot set any option for duplicating or mirroring the display with `EnumDisplaySettingsEx()` . Your Link just demonstrates how to set a screen as primary.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Windows7 you can use `DisplaySwitch.exe` file with parameters `/extend` and `/clone`

Comment: Glad to know this executable exists! Saved me a lot of time. Also works in Window 8. Wonder if it will work in Vista.

Comment: And Windows 11 22000.51! :)