# Auto switch to clone (lcd & laptop monitor) display?

Tags: c#, unmanaged, monitor

How do I detect a plugged monitor in a laptop/netbook and enable clone-display view once it is detected?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`EnumDisplaySettingsEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162612(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here is the similar question : [How do I enable a second monitor in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/233411/791745)