# vb .net - how to change the second monitor extend/duplicate

Tags: .net, vb.net, multiple-monitors

I'm creating a project called 'Wandows' (You can view the project [here](http://alex8834.wix.com/wandows#!download/s9fky))

I'm trying to get my application to change the second monitor mode programmatically. So that if the monitor is on duplicate it will switch to extend or if it is on extend it will switch to duplicate!

I have found a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233411/how-do-i-enable-a-second-monitor-in-c) - however it is in C# Not vb .net!

I'm using vb .net as my programming language

Can someone please explain how to do this!

Comment: The question might be in C#, but the accepted answer is for C++. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(v=vs.71).aspx - and this: http://www.pinvoke.net/

Comment: Okay, I don't quite understand what that page is all about, can you please explain what I'm looking at in this page!

Comment: Which one of them? The first one is about P/Invoking WinAPI methods, and the second one is a site where you can find the VB.NET/C# declaration for them. [The answer in the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/233826/3740093) you provided uses WinAPI functions which in VB.NET or C# need to be P/Invoked.